# unable to setstate in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate, react-state

I am trying to use function components in which eventoffset value is initially set to -1. 
when user clicks "ok" to save the values in backend func saveEvent is called and in that calOffsetUTC is calculating the new offset and utc values which set the state values accordingly. 
I am trying to call addTimeline() with new offset and utc values but it seems state values are not updated.

where am i going wrong.

Any help appreciated.

```
const Dialog = (props: Props) => {
  let currentdate = new Date(Date.now());
  const [eventDate, seteventDate] = React.useState(currentdate);
  const [eventOffset, seteventOffset] = React.useState(-1);
  const [eventUTC, seteventUTC] = React.useState();
  const calcOffsetUTC = (date) => {
    var selectedDate = date;

    if (eventOffset == -1) {
      var offset = selectedDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60;
      var utc = selectedDate.valueOf();
      seteventOffset(offset);              //trying to set state of "eventoffset"
      seteventTime(utc);
    }
  }
  const saveEvent = () => {
    calcOffsetUTC(eventDate);
    props.addTimeline(eventUTC, eventOffset); //latest eventoffset value is not found here.

    }
    const buttons = [];
    buttons.push({ text: translate("ok"), icon: "ok", callback: () => saveEvent() });

    return <Dialog buttons={buttons}  ></Dialog>;
}
```

Comment: This is not the correct way to set a state in react. set a state like this  `this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 })`

Comment: is it? could you give me inputs

Comment: try to do `this.setState({ seteventOffset: offset })`

Comment: @HarshPatel OP is using Hooks...

Comment: Possible duplicarte of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately/54069332#54069332

Comment: @HarshPatel OP isn't using a class-based component, it's a functional component using `useState` hook.

Comment: so if my understanding is correct, seteventOffset(offset) is wrong way to set state in function components. instead i have to use "useeffect"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few options to use correct updated state values

Return the next state computed values

```
const Dialog = (props: Props) => {
  let currentdate = new Date(Date.now());
  const [eventDate, seteventDate] = React.useState(currentdate);
  const [eventOffset, seteventOffset] = React.useState(-1);
  const [eventUTC, seteventUTC] = React.useState();

  const calcOffsetUTC = (date) => {
    var selectedDate = date;

    if (eventOffset === -1) {
      var offset = selectedDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60;
      var utc = selectedDate.valueOf();
      seteventOffset(offset); 
      seteventTime(utc);
      return { offset, utc }; // return computed values
    }
    return {}; // return defined object for unhappy path
  }

  const saveEvent = () => {
    const { offset, utc } = calcOffsetUTC(eventDate);
    offset && utc && props.addTimeline(utc, offset); // use returned values
  }

  const buttons = [];
  buttons.push({ text: translate("ok"), icon: "ok", callback: () => saveEvent() });

  return <Dialog buttons={buttons}></Dialog>;
}
```

Do it all in the handler

```
const Dialog = (props: Props) => {
  let currentdate = new Date(Date.now());
  const [eventDate, seteventDate] = React.useState(currentdate);
  const [eventOffset, seteventOffset] = React.useState(-1);
  const [eventUTC, seteventUTC] = React.useState();

  const saveEvent = () => {
    var selectedDate = eventDate;

    if (eventOffset === -1) {
      var offset = selectedDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60;
      var utc = selectedDate.valueOf();
      seteventOffset(offset); 
      seteventTime(utc);
      props.addTimeline(utc, offset);
    }
  }

  const buttons = [];
  buttons.push({ text: translate("ok"), icon: "ok", callback: () => saveEvent() });

  return <Dialog buttons={buttons}></Dialog>;
}
```

Use effect hook

```
const Dialog = (props: Props) => {
  let currentdate = new Date(Date.now());
  const [eventDate, seteventDate] = React.useState(currentdate);
  const [eventOffset, seteventOffset] = React.useState(-1);
  const [eventUTC, seteventUTC] = React.useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    props.addTimeline(eventUTC, eventOffset); // use latest values here
  }, [eventOffset, eventUTC]);

  const calcOffsetUTC = (date) => {
    var selectedDate = date;

    if (eventOffset === -1) {
      var offset = selectedDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60;
      var utc = selectedDate.valueOf();
      seteventOffset(offset);
      seteventTime(utc);
    }
  }

  const saveEvent = () => {
    calcOffsetUTC(eventDate);
  }

  const buttons = [];
  buttons.push({ text: translate("ok"), icon: "ok", callback: () => saveEvent() 
});

  return <Dialog buttons={buttons}  ></Dialog>;
}
```

*NOTE:* With the effect you may as well just make `calcOffsetUTC` the callback since as this point `saveEvent` is merely proxying the date.

Comment: thanks drew :) much appreciated and understood clearly :)